# Self Improvement Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burnination

Until just now as a result of this question, [How to overlap a continuous line on itself?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92466/how-to-overlap-a-continuous-line-on-itself), I didn't even realize we had a [self-improvement](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-improvement)

if there's no objections I'm going to destroy it. I have no idea what purpose it aims to serve. If anyone disagrees I'll wait 48 hours before destroying it so make your voice heard.

Comment: *Burn, baby, burn*

Comment: Maybe you could make it a synonym of [tag:training] or [tag:learning] ? Or maybe even [tag:skillset] ?

Comment: @PieBie I think you just found more tags that need burning. Not sure on the skillset but the others can all be folded into [education](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education)

Comment: All good to me @Ryan. All I do is report it, the mods can do the heavy lifting :D